# Motivation of differential form of first law of thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics, energy-conservation, differentiation

There are two forms of first law of thermodynamics. Is there formal way to derive the differential form from the integral one, that is is it possible to prove
$dU=\delta Q +\delta W$ from $\Delta U=Q+W$ using predicate logic?
Is there formal way to describe what $\delta W$ and $\delta Q$ are using predicate logic?

Comment: There exist the notion of Geometrothermodynamics, which is a manifold description of thermodynamics, that can give a more formal proof

Comment: I would recommend using the differential form only for reversible process paths.

Comment: I don't use predicate logic. When I teach intro thermo I just tell students to think of the infinitesimals as being smaller than any finite quantity in the problem, so we can throw out higher-order terms and divide one by the other to get a secant line that turns into a tangent line (derivative). If you're asking why we can get the exact energy $dU$ rather than an inexact differential, $\delta U$, I think you can get there from the integral form of the First Law and smoothness assumptions.

Comment: I am interested in formal proof. I don't get it when this is explained in terms of infinitesimals. There must be formal proof.